# WinAPI FindWindow

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2012, findwindow, createwindowex

I am building a win32 application in visual studio 2012. I have 4 disabled buttons created with the following code:

```
HWND hWndButton=CreateWindowEx(NULL, 
        L"BUTTON",
        L"APP1",
        WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON|WS_DISABLED|BS_ICON,
        40,
        40,
        180,
        140,
        hWnd,
        (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON1,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL);
```

What I want to do is to enable the buttons as the application runs. I tried to use findwindow to find and enable the first button but it doesn't find it. My code is:

```
HWND hwB1 = FindWindow(L"BUTTON",L"APP1");
if (hwB1 !=0)   MessageBox(NULL,L"FOUND",L"Button Found",MB_OK);
EnableWindow(hwB1,true);
```

Am I doing something wrong? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindWindow()` finds top-level windows, not child windows.

If you really do want to look up a child window by name, you can use the `FindWindowEx()` function, but using the ID is usually more efficient.

The function that does this is `GetDlgItem()`. This looks up child windows by their ID, which you provide when you create them.

```
HWND hwB1 = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BUTTON1);
```

`hWnd` is the parent window, and `IDC_BUTTON1` is the ID.

Another alternative is to simply store the window handle that's returned when you create the child window - `hWndButton` in your code example - and then you don't need to look it up at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FindWindowEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx),

```
HWND hwB1=FindWindowEx(hWnd/*Parent window*/,
                       hWndButton/*Child window*/,
                       "BUTTON"/*Class of the child window*/,
                       "APP1"/*Title of the child window*/);
```

This is a better method when the control ID is unknown.

Comment: @aschipfl: Does this explanation help?